# Running local javascript to any external URL loaded in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Can't find any references to how it is done exactly.

I am new to cordova/phonegap and the in my project I have generated a cordova jar file which is imported as a library to my project to implement its cordovawebview class.

How can I add my own javascript to any url that gets loaded in the webview?

Thanks in advance,
ChillY

Answer (score 0):

You need to use in-App Browser to load any url load in the webview

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Documentation

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: I can load any URL in my CordovaWebView class object, but according to that documentation, I can see that I can insert my own CSS into the view, what about javascript though?

Comment: you can use this example. var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');